# UIWebView refer to local resource from remote html

Tags: ios, uiwebview, resources

F.e. we have UIWebView with loaded page from `http://blabla/index.html` and I want it to load some local resources (js/bridge.js, css/main.css, ...).
So html would be like

```
<head>
<script src="file:///.../js/bridge.js"></script>
</head>
```

But how exactly I should refer to local resources? Maybe I should open local httpd and refer to it like `http://127.0.0.1/js/bridge.js` ?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, if you want a mix of local an network resources you must:

1. Load download the HTML and then use `loadHTMLString` to load the it, using a `baseURL` of the local file system. I've not been successful loading local resources when the URL is a server-side URL. I've always had to download the HTML and load it directly.
2. All network sources need to be fully qualified (i.e. with "http://..."). Since we're going to set the base URL to be the local file system, and local URL references on the server code won't work. They have to be fully qualified.
3. Any iPhone-local sources can be locally referenced (i.e. without any `file://` or `http://` prefix), or you can pass the base URL as a HTTP REQUEST parameter and do server-side scripting to embed this unique URL.

Thus, my iOS code looks like:

```
// get my bundle local URL

NSURL *bundleUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];

// download the html from the server

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// load that html into my web view using a the bundle as the base URL

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:bundleUrl];
```

So, for this to work, my HTML might look like:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>image from iOS file system using local reference</td>
    <td><img src="sample.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>server image</td>
    <td><img src="http://myserverurl.com/sampleonserver.png" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I'm using `img` tags, but I suspect the same is true for your tags, too. I'm also assuming that your local references are within the bundle, but if they're within the Documents folder, I think it's equivalent. Just make sure that all local references point to a relative directory within the local file system and that all of the server requests are fully qualified.